# Metadata on Composite Functions (i.e. when using comp)

Tags: clojure, metadata

I'm using Clojure 1.5.1 and I just encountered the following on my (Leiningen) REPL:

```
(let [inc-x ^:some-metadata (comp inc :x)]
  (meta inc-x)) ;; => nil
```

No metadata attached. When I write out the function, though:

```
(let [inc-x ^:some-metadata (fn [m] (-> m :x inc))]
  (meta inc-x)) ;; => {:some-metadata true}

;; more closely to `comp`
(let [inc-x ^:some-metadata (fn [& args] (-> (apply :x args) inc))]
  (meta inc-x)) ;; => {:some-metadata true}
```

Aha, maybe the result of `comp` can just not deal with metadata. Nope, it can:

```
(let [inc-x (with-meta (comp inc :x) {:some-metadata true})]
  (meta inc-x)) ;; => {:some-metadata true}
```

I guess the reader cannot handle `^:some-metadata` correctly here. Any ideas why?

**FYI**: `constantly` shows the same behaviour, so does `complement`and probably a series of others.

Comment: I'm curious to know also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the reader works as it should and attaches metadata to the form `(comp inc :x)`, which is a regular function call. Then the form is evaluated and returns a function, which does not inherit the metadata. On the other hand, `fn` is a special form, which is handled differently (haven't found explicit info on this in the documentation though).

Comment: Makes sense. The reader attaches the metadata to the forms it encounters, not their result (since it cannot know it). Didn't think of that, so, thanks!